# Jquery Second Select box is not populating when i select first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following ajax code which will trigger when first select box is selected

```
$('#select_modal_name').on('change',function(){
      $('#loader').show();
       var myselect='';
      var pageurl =  'http://localhost/demo/public/';
        $.ajax({
        url: pageurl+'/brand-name',
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data){
             $('#loader').hide();

               $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
                   myselect+='<option value="'+value.id+'" >'+value.brand_name+'</option>';   


});

 $('#try-this').append(myselect);

console.log(myselect);

         }

});
});
```

html code

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Model</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <select id="select_modal_name" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true">
          <option value="AK" selected>---Select--</option>
            @foreach($data as $key=>$val)
           <option value="{{$val->id}}">{{$val->brand_name}}</option>
           @endforeach;

        </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                     <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Model Parts Name <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                     <select id="basic select-parts-name" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control " data-live-search="true">

          <div id="try-this" class="try-this" ></div>
         <!--  <option value="AK" selected>---Select--</option>--->

        </select>
                        </div>
```

Even i have alerted the output in success of ajax data of option is printing.only issue is its not appending to select box

Comment: You are appending to the `div`, not the select box. Try `<select id="try-this"...`

Comment: @WesFoster.Thanks i have tried that also but no use.Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't read your mind there

Comment: i have alerted myselect in success but it prints all options

Comment: @WesFoster.Thanks i have resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes Finally Resolved my problem

The issue is i am using selectpicker js to design select box.I have appended option value using  class name and added selectpicker refresh

```
$('.selectpicker').append(myselect);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Now its working fine.